# How to find duplicates in file

Tags: python

Basically I want to try to make a system where when you type in your ID number, and do it again with the same number, it should show an error. I've tried to look for some solutions online, but just couldn't seem to find one that would actually work. This is the code I've done so far:

```
import sys
N = 0
while N < 2:
    ID = input("Please input ID code ")
    if (len(ID)) == 6:
        with open('ID1.txt', 'a') as file:
            file.write(ID + ' ')
            file.write('\n')
        N += 1
        print("ID length: Valid")
    else:
        print("ID Code: Error")
        sys.exit()
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: you have to store the already used IDs. For example in a list. Then check if it's already in the list.

Comment: You want to throw an error when the id typed second time ie equal the one first time or if the id typed in is allready contained in the file?

Comment: You could use a set to store the IDs. for small numbers of IDs there is no appreciable difference in time of access, but say you had several million IDs. the set would be faster

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, with your code, is to load the text file, split it into its IDs by splitting by newline, then seeing whether the ID is in this new list:

```
N = 1
while N <= 2:
    input_id = input('Type your ID: ')

    assert input_id == 6, 'Invalid ID length'

    with open('IDs.txt', 'r+') as ids:
        id_list = ids.read().split('\n')
        if input_id in id_list:
            print('This ID already exists')
            N += 1
            continue
        else:
            ids.write('\n'+input_id)
            print('valid ID')
            break
```

But the cleaner way is to do it using a JSON file. This way, you can load the list directly, and there will be fewer chances of formatting errors

```
import json

N = 1
while N <= 2:
    file = open('IDs.json', 'r')
    ids = json.load(file)
    file.close()

    input_id= input('enter your ID:')
    assert input_id == 6, 'Invalid ID length'

    if int(input_id) in ids:
        print('This ID already exists')
        N += 1
        continue
    else:
        ids.append(int(input_id))
        json.dumps('IDs.json', ids)
        print('ID accepted')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code verifies if the ID exists in file if not , enters 2 Unique ID's into the file

```
N = 0
while N < 2:
    ID = raw_input("Please input ID code ")
    if (len(ID)) == 6:
        with open('ID1.txt', 'a+') as f:
            if not any(ID == x.rstrip('\r\n') for x in f):
                f.write(ID + '\n')
                N += 1
```